# Interaction between {} and select

Tags: jq

Here's my test data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "id-1",
    "tags": {
      "key": "name",
      "value": "name-1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "id-2"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to simplify the output, to show the 'name' field if present, and always show the id. For example, this script almost works:

```
~ $ cat testdata | jq '.[] | {id, name: .tags.value}'

{
  "id": "id-1",
  "name": "name-1"
}
{
  "id": "id-2",
  "name": null
}
```

When I try to add in a guard against .keys not existing and filter for the section of 'keys' I care about, here's what happens:

```
~ $ cat testdata | jq '.[] | {id, name: (select(.tags.key == "name") | .tags.value)}'

{
  "id": "id-1",
  "name": "name-1"
}
```

I assume {} is somehow ending up with a zero-length array instead of 'null'. What should I be using instead of |? What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to produce:

```
{"id":"id-1","name":"name-1"}
{"id":"id-2"}
```

then the following three expressions are essentially equivalent solutions:

```
.[] | if .tags.key == "name" then {id, name: .tags.value} else {id} end

.[] | {id} + (if .tags.key == "name" then {name: .tags.value} else {} end)

.[] | (select(.tags.key  == "name") | {id, name: .tags.value}) // {id}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a conditional removal using [`if .. then .. else .. end`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else):

```
| if .name == null then del(.name) else . end
```

to the end of your filter to get rid of the .name key when its value is `null`.
With your test data, the following

```
  .[]
| {id, name:.tags.value }
| if .name == null then del(.name) else . end
```

produces

```
{
  "id": "id-1",
  "name": "name-1"
}
{
  "id": "id-2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem using: `[POSSIBLY_MATCHED_EXPRESSION][0]`, in this case:

```
 cat testdata | jq '.[] | {id, name: ([select(.tags.key == "name") | .tags.value][0])}'
```

Comment: Note that this "solution" adds `name: null` to the output. The question made it sound like you don't want to have the name at all. There are more straightforward solutions and `[.x][0]` is a confusing way to write `.x // null`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, if you wanted to include a name only if it existed, I'd do this:

```
map({id} + with_entries(select(.key == "tags") | .value))
```

Otherwise if you don't mind `null` names:

```
map({id, name: with_entries(select(.key == "tags") | .value) | .name})
```

---

Here's a more general solution if you have other "tags" so it's not hardcoded to only accept `name` values.

This assumes that any object value is actually a key/value pair.

```
map(with_entries(if .value | type == "object" then .value else . end))
```

Or if `tags` is the only dynamic property:

```
map(with_entries(if .key == "tags" then .value else . end))
```

Comment: The sample data is included right in the question--I'm not sure what you're imagining, because this makes no sense to me. I do in fact only care about 'name' values, though. [Edited question to clarify that the filter is on purpose]

Comment: I'm just saying, if the data you're showing is a highly simplified version of your real data. If there are more properties, other "tags" and whatnot, this can handle any of your cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two additional possible solutions to the problem:

- `.[] | { id, name: .tags | select(.key == "name").value } // { id }`
- `.[] | { id } + ({ name: .tags | select(.key == "name").value } // {})`

Output:

```json
{
  "id": "id-1",
  "name": "name-1"
}
{
  "id": "id-2"
}
```

Or to generate output with `name: null`:

- `.[] | { id, name: (.tags | select(.key == "name").value // null) }`

Output:

```json
{
  "id": "id-1",
  "name": "name-1"
}
{
  "id": "id-2",
  "name": null
}
```